# What is the strategy of SharedString on Merging data?

Tags: fluid-framework

I go through the introduction but only find DDS like SharedMap where they are using last-writer-wins policy. How about the SharedString? I am considering a collaborative editing scenario with the SharedString. I have read OT and CRDT. So I am wondering how SharedString or other DDS handled the merge conflict.

Answer (score 0):

The shared string readme goes into some details about how merging works:
https://github.com/microsoft/FluidFramework/blob/main/packages/dds/sequence/README.md